# How to get token form query parameter and add it into proxy_set_header?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to take a token from URL, save it and add it into proxy_set_header(nginx). This is the URL:

```
http://localhost:8900/dashboards?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

This my code:

```
location / {
            set $apiToken "";   

        if ($args ~ "^token=(.+)") {
              set $apiToken $1;
            }
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        proxy_set_header X-User-custom $apiToken;
 }
```

I will appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use  `$arg_token` to get the token parameter in your url.

Comment: you mean to add int in proxy_set_header like that:
 proxy_set_header $arg_token

Comment: i want to add on every request after that